Copper grounding to water line
when grounding residential home with 4 gauge copper wire to main water pipe, does wire need to touch panel also? I already have panel grounded with 6 gauge copper wire touching same water pipe.

Are you grounding the home or grounding the panel?  Please clarify.

In the US, using a water pipe as ground is no longer acceptable by code.  You really should drive proper grounding rods and run real ground wires... Or, if you can't run ground wires for some reason, install a ground fault circuit interrupter (GFCI) to provide some protection against electric shock.

Do you have other grounding electrodes besides the water service line?

We grounded the panel with 6 gauge wire (we used 8ft grounding rods) and now we are grounding home to main water pipe. Yes, we have gfci’s throughout the house.

We also grounded gas line with 6 gauge wire to water line, which runs to panel. But my question is, the separate 4 gauge cooper wire, does it have to run to panel also or is it ok as long as it’s grounded with grounding rod?

What size are the feeder wires to main breaker? (If size is undeterminable we can guess based on amperage.)
